# Adding Theme per device

Tags: sxa

I am using `Sitecore 9.3 and SXA`, I want to add different themes for different devices, is there a possibility to add a theme per device?

Comment: Not out of the box, why would you want different themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different themes for different devices per (SXA) site. This is done by the following steps (assuming you already have different themes in your `Media Library`).

**1. Set the site compatible themes**

- Go to `Site Settings` and open the `Site Configuration` tab
- Select the necessary themes under `Compatible Themes`
  [image: Set Compatible Themes]

**2. Set a theme per device**

- Go the site `Page Designs` and open the `Styling` tab
- Select the correct theme per device (devices are located under: `/sitecore/layout/Devices`)
  [image: Set a theme per devices]